# Insert text followed by keypress event in an input box using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to prepend and append a data that is interfaced from an equipment to an input box of a website and finally submit the output data into that website with a submit button using the following JS code

```
document.querySelectorAll("tbody.md-table > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(7) > jhi-alpha-numeric:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(1)")
    .forEach(o => {
      if (o.value && !isNaN(o.value) && o.value < 0.9) o.value = `NON REACTIVE (${o.value}`;
    });
```

If interfaced data from equipment is `0.7`, then using my code, the output data becomes  `NON REACTIVE (0.7)`. But after I submit my data by hitting the submit button and then check what has entered into the website, it doesnt have the prepended `NON REACTIVE (` and the appended `)`values. What gets entered into the system is only the `0.7`.

I tried troubleshooting and realized that before hitting the submit button, if I click on the input box and hit the space button at the end of the output data and then hit submit, its gets submitted like the way I want.
So, I am trying to execute a **mouse click event followed by a space keypress event at the end of the output data** , that is, after the  `NON REACTIVE (0.7)`

Will this be possible? I will be highly grateful if you can help me with this. Thank you in advance.